# Efficiently output query result with jQuery .ajax()?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Sorry in advance if what I am going to ask is silly, I am having trouble understanding the asynchronous HTTP responses. I am trying to use `jQuery` `.ajax()` with `PHP` and `MySQL` in the following context:

- when page loads I will query and return all the applications for a particular id, and then I will use a `while` loop to output them;
- also there is a button that allows the user to add new application for that particular id -> on click it:

  - shows a hidden form and gets the values in the inputs;
  - sends the data to `PHP` using the `.ajax()` method;
  - performs the insert.
- and I am **stuck at this point**

I need to output the newly added application above the existing ones, but the query and `while` will do it only when an synchronous HTTP request is sent.

I tried to use the `.success()` but the HTML I need to output inside is really long and I am afraid it will be hard to maintain having outputs from both `PHP` `while` loop and `jQuery`.

Can you please help me understand an efficient way to do this? I have never dealt with asynchronous HTTP request before. Also, I am can't use any `JavaScript` templating libraries.

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Why not insert the new entry into the page directly based on the information you're sending to do the insert rather than waiting for a response or refreshing the whole list?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, please? You mean to return `html` based `json` from the `php` and directly append that?

Comment: No, i mean take the same data you are submitting to php and create a dom node to insert without the help of php. You already have the application name/info etc that you are adding, the only thing missing is the ID. if it's important that the ID be part of the dom too, you can always add that after.

Comment: And only use the `.ajax()` to perform the db query without waiting for json a response? I got it now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Right. You already have all the information you need to update the ui, so all the ajax request needs to do is ensure the database gets updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm going to try it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ajax postback typically implies some sort of JSON-based web api behind it.  Examples of this on the internet abound.

https://www.lennu.net/jquery-ajax-example-with-json-response/
http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/create-restful-services-api-in-php.html

Your REST endpoint should return the minimal amount of JSON data you need.  At which point you can use that data to update/bind to elements in your DOM inside your "done" or "success" callback.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I will keep reading more until things get clearer.